# How to join two Dataset<Row> in Spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have two Dataset in Java Spark, like these:

[image]

[image]

I want to obtain a joined Dataset where there are all keys of both datasets and the two columns 'val1' and 'val2', null if one is missing, like this

[image]

I've tried with fullouter join:

```
ds1.join(ds2,col("key1").equalTo(col("key")), "fullouter")
```

but it works only if key1 set is equal to key2 set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type in the join condition, the column on 2nd dataset should be "key2"

`ds1.join(ds2,ds1("key1").equalTo(ds2("key2")), "fullouter")`

The result won't have a column "key" rather - key1, key2, value1, value2.